# MS Word Object Model structure: dealing with fields

Tags: python, vba, ms-word, lyx

Goal: Programmatically process a word document with bibliographic citations (ultimately from EndNote) and convert it to another format (LyX).

How do I go through the document so that I can recreate it?  Where a citation occurs, I only want to output a reference to the cited work, not the characters that appear in the document.  Where the bibliography occurs, I only want to output a command to insert the bibliography, not the textual sources.

Sample Input (as it appears in MS Word when reveal codes is off):

> As was said[1] it’s a long way to tip
>
> 1. Agha, S., Patterns of use of the female condom after one year of mass marketing. AIDS >Educ Prev, 2001. 13(1): p. 55-64.

Desired Output style (pseudo-LaTeX):

```
As was said\ref{bib526} it’s a long way to tip.

\bibliography
```

The `bib526` would be extracted from the `Field.Code`.

The following program illustrates several oddities:

1. `Document.Characters.Count` is much shorter than the actual number of characters in the document range.  This appears to reflect the many hidden characters in, e.g., `Field.Code`, but I'm not sure if the characters that appear in the bibliography count.
2. The `Field` appears to be repeated across some of the printed characters in "[1]".  How can I assure I only output it once, and that I do not output any of the printed characters for the reference?  (There are 2 fields in some cases because there is both a citation field and a hyperlink field).
3. Apparently `Document` may have several stories in `StoryRanges`, though my little test only has one.  Which should I pay attention to?

[Without this the next block isn't formatted right.  Don't know why.]

```
Public Sub inspect()
    Dim a As Document
    Dim r As Range
    Set a = ActiveDocument
    Set r = a.Range
    Debug.Print "Document ranges from"; r.Start; "to"; r.End; "with";
        r.Characters.Count; "Characters"
    For ic = 11 To 16
        Set r = a.Characters(ic)
        Debug.Print "Character"; ic; r.Start; r.End; r.Fields.Count; r.Text
        Next ic
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Document ranges from 0 to 6137 with 659 Characters
Columns are
A = position in `Document.Characters`
B, C = start, end of corresponding range (often more than 1 character!)
D = # of fields in the character
E = printed representation of the character
          A   B    C  D E
Character 11  10  11  0 d
Character 12  11  1559  2 [
Character 13  1559  1607  1 1
Character 14  1607  1609  2 ]
Character 15  1609  1610  0  
Character 16  1610  1611  0 i
```

I might do the actual program in Python, not VBA.